# Regex backreference dentro de grupo com OR

Tags: regex

Estou tentando referenciar um valor dentro de um "OR". Exemplo, tenho o texto dentro do arquivo:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC;
ALTER TABLE ABC;
```

Preciso que o `ABC` (nome tabela) do `ALTER` seja sempre igual do `CREATE`, já tentei a seguinte expressão mas sem sucesso.

```
(CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(\w+).+;|ALTER\s+TABLE\s+\2.+;)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa do "OR" (`|`), pois ele significa que somente um dos trechos já satisfará a expressão. No caso, você tem o "CREATE" de um lado do `|` e o "ALTER" do outro. Quando a regex capturar um deles, já considerará que a expressão foi satisfeita e [não avaliará o resto](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).

No seu caso, a regex encontra o "CREATE" e para por aí. Como o "ALTER" está do outro lado do `|`, ele não precisa mais ser avaliado (pois já foi encontrado um *match* no "CREATE").

Se você quer verificar o texto inteiro (tanto o "CREATE" quanto o "ALTER"), retire o `|`.

Outro detalhe é que entre o nome da tabela e o `;` não há espaços, mas você usou `.+` (**um** ou mais caracteres). No caso, como pode ter espaços entre o nome da tabela e o `;`, mas também pode não ter nenhum, sugiro trocar para `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços).

```
(CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(\w+)\s*;\s*ALTER\s+TABLE\s+\2\s*;)
```

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/gjTuqR/5) esta regex em funcionamento.

---

Não ficou claro qual linguagem você está usando, mas geralmente o `\s` já considera as quebras de linha, então colocar o `\s*` antes de "ALTER" faz com que sejam considerados tanto espaços quanto quebra de linhas.

Mas se quiser obrigar a ter pelo menos uma quebra de linha, pode acrescentar um `[\n\r]+`:

```
(CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(\w+)\s*;[\n\r]+\s*ALTER\s+TABLE\s+\2\s*;)
```

Ou, se quiser ser mais detalhista, use `(?:\r?\n)+` - o `\r` (*carriage return*) é usado no Windows, juntamente com o `\n` (*line feed*), enquanto que em sistemas Unix somente o `\n` é usado. Assim, `\r?\n` faz com que o `\r` seja opcional e esta expressão considere as quebras de linhas em ambos os sistemas. Em seguida, `(?:` faz com que a expressão seja um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), para não criar mais um grupo à toa (dependendo da posição do grupo, isso [pode mudar o valor do *backreference* `\2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579103)). E o `+` faz com que uma ou mais quebras de linha sejam consideradas.